# Xcode remove selected color from an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am having a image view in my view controller, i want to remove a color from whole image.

Does anyone knows how to remove a color from whole image?

See the below images.
Red color is removed from whole image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you wish to turn all pixels of exactly the picked RGB value into white? Or are you trying to do something more subtle and remove all red hue from every pixel value? (I think you're after the former but not sure.)

Comment: I want to turn all pixels into clear color not to remove red hue from whole image. Image i have uploaded is sample, image could be any. @BenZotto

Comment: Then you can create a new bitmap context, draw the image into it, and then loop through each pixel. If it matches your target color, change it to transparent. Then create a new UIImage from this context.

Comment: i have already done this thing, but only some pixels are being removed from  image, i have tried using different images as well.